# parser xml в PowerShell

Tags: xml, парсер, powershell

есть вот такой парсер на .net

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace ParseSample
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string FindedUch = "Подразделение которое ищем"; // Подразделение которое ищем
        List<string> Mails = new List<string>();
        //Читаем Файл
        string inData = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"E:\erp.xml");
        //Ищем Все <d:element>
        Regex r = new Regex(@"<d:element>.*?</d:element>", RegexOptions.Singleline);
        var res = r.Matches(inData);
        //Ищем в каждом элементе нужные строки
        Regex AdresEp = new Regex(@"<d:АдресЭП>.*?</d:АдресЭП>");
        Regex Podreazd = new Regex(@"<d:Подразделение>.*?</d:Подразделение>");
        foreach (var localRes in res)
        {
            try
            {
                string localResStr = localRes.ToString();
                string podrazdStr = Podreazd.Matches(localResStr)[0].ToString().Replace(@"<d:Подразделение>", "").Replace(@"</d:Подразделение>", "");
                string AdresEpStr = AdresEp.Matches(localResStr)[0].ToString().Replace(@"<d:АдресЭП>", "").Replace(@"</d:АдресЭП>", "");
                if (podrazdStr == FindedUch) Mails.Add(AdresEpStr);
            }
            catch { }
        }
        //Выводим список Мылов
        foreach (var s in Mails) Console.WriteLine(s);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"E:\erp_mails.txt", Mails);
    }
}
}
```

нужен аналогичный по функционалу парсер в powershell.
xml в котором производиться поиск выглядит так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed>
  <entry>
    <content>
      <m:properties xmlns:d="d" xmlns:m="m">
        <d:СтрокиТаблицы>
            <d:element>
            <d:element>
            <d:element>
            <d:element>
            ....
            <d:element> 
        </d:СтрокиТаблицы>
      </m:properties>
    </content>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

Где "d:element" содержит информацию:

```
<d:element>
  <d:ФизическоеЛицо>User User User</d:ФизическоеЛицо>
  <d:Сотрудник>User User User</d:Сотрудник>
  <d:Должность>Должность Юзера</d:Должность>
  <d:ДолжностьПометкаУдаления>Нет</d:ДолжностьПометкаУдаления>
  <d:СотрудникПометкаУдаления>Нет</d:СотрудникПометкаУдаления>
  <d:ФизическоеЛицоПометкаУдаления>Нет</d:ФизическоеЛицоПометкаУдаления>
  <d:ТабельныйНомер>№№№№      </d:ТабельныйНомер>
  <d:ФИО>User User User</d:ФИО>
  <d:Пол>Мужской</d:Пол>
  <d:ОсновноеМестоРаботы>Да</d:ОсновноеМестоРаботы>
  <d:ДатаРождения>хх.хх.1991 0:00:00</d:ДатаРождения>
  <d:ДатаПриема>хх.хх.хххх 0:00:00</d:ДатаПриема>
  <d:ДатаУвольнения>хх.хх.хххх 0:00:00</d:ДатаУвольнения>
  <d:РуководительФизЛицо>User User User</d:РуководительФизЛицо>
  <d:РуководительФизЛицоПометкаНаУдаление>Нет</d:РуководительФизЛицоПометкаНаУдаление>
  <d:ФизЛицоМобТел>+хххххххххх</d:ФизЛицоМобТел>
  <d:ФизЛицоРабТел>ххх</d:ФизЛицоРабТел>
  <d:Адрес>хххххх, ххххххх хх, ххххх-ххххх р-н, хххххх х, ххххххх ул, хххх № хххх</d:Адрес>
  <d:АдресЭП>user@domen.ru</d:АдресЭП>
  <d:РуководительПользователь>User userovich</d:РуководительПользователь>
  <d:РуководительПользовательПометкаНаУдаление>Нет</d:РуководительПользовательПометкаНаУдаление>
  <d:Пользователь>User User User</d:Пользователь>
  <d:ПользовательПометкаНаУдаления>Нет</d:ПользовательПометкаНаУдаления>
  <d:РуководительСотрудник>User User User (осн)</d:РуководительСотрудник>
  <d:РуководительСотрудникПометкаНаУдаление>Нет</d:РуководительСотрудникПометкаНаУдаление>
  <d:Недействителен>Нет</d:Недействителен>
  <d:Подразделение>xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx </d:Подразделение>
  <d:ПодразделениеПометкаУдаления>Нет</d:ПодразделениеПометкаУдаления>
  <d:Территория>(п. хххххх-хххххх)</d:Территория>
  <d:SID>xxxxxxxxxx</d:SID>
  <d:ЛогинАД>\\хххх\Userr</d:ЛогинАД>
  <d:GUID>xxxxxxxxxx</d:GUID>
  <d:Фамилия>Юзер</d:Фамилия>
  <d:Имя>Юзер</d:Имя>
  <d:Отчество>Юзерович</d:Отчество>
  <d:ПодразделениеGUID>xxxxxxxxxx</d:ПодразделениеGUID>
  <d:ДолжностьGUID>xxxxxxxxxx</d:ДолжностьGUID>
  <d:ПодразделениеРус>xxxxxxxxxx</d:ПодразделениеРус>
  <d:ДолжностьРус>xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx</d:ДолжностьРус>
  <d:ПодразделениеАнг>xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx</d:ПодразделениеАнг>
  <d:ДолжностьАнг>xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx</d:ДолжностьАнг>
  <d:РуководительСотрудникGUID>xxxxxxxxxx-b160-xxxxxxxxxx-822d-xxxxxxxxxx</d:РуководительСотрудникGUID>
  <d:СотрудникGUID>xxxxxxxxxx</d:СотрудникGUID>
  <d:ФизическоеЛицоGUID>xxxxxxxxxx</d:ФизическоеЛицоGUID>
  <d:РуководительФизЛицоGUID>xxxxxxxxxx</d:РуководительФизЛицоGUID>
  <d:РуководительПользовательGUID>xxxxxxxxxx</d:РуководительПользовательGUID>
  <d:ТерриторияGUID>xxxxxxxxxx</d:ТерриторияGUID>
  <d:ДатаИзменения>xxxxxxxxxx</d:ДатаИзменения>
</d:element>
```

Нужно парсить и выгружать поле `<d:АдресЭП>` для определенного отдела и отправлять дальше по конвейеру в exchange.

Comment: почитайте про [XPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms256471.aspx). Это прямой путь, чтобы делать запросы к XML-данным.

Answer (score 2):

Всем спасибо, разобрался как сделать через linq  запрос:

```
 `(Select-Xml -Path E:\name.xml -XPath '//d:СтрокиТаблицы' -Namespace @{d='d';m='m'}).Node.element.Where{$_.Подразделение -eq '$dit'}.АдресЭП | Out-File E:\mail_erpp1.txt`
```

Спасибо товарищам с cyberforum.ru за подсказку!

Answer (score 1):

```
# читаем из файла в объект XmlDocument
[xml]$doc = gc test.xml

# проходим по нужным элементам
foreach ($elem in $doc.feed.entry.content.properties.СтрокиТаблицы.element)
{
  # отфильтровываем элемент по значению подразделения
  if ($elem.Подразделение -eq 'xxx')
  {
    # получаем адрес
    echo $elem.АдресЭП
  }
}
```

Comment: я находил такую конструкцию. Проблема в том что мне нежно еще одно условие поиска, а именно, набор "АдресЭП" в рамкам конкретного  «ПодразделениеРус».

Comment: @Tahugava - обновил код